# delete tables on import of dump created by mysqldump

Tags: mysql, backup, mariadb, restore, mysqldump

There are 2 copies of the same database on 2 different storages which need to be in sync.

For example, database named *test_db* contains tables *T1,T2,T3* tables. 
*T2,T3* are deleted.
Dump of the 1st copy is created using:

```
mysqldump --login-path=lp --add-drop-table test_db > dump.sql
```

and imported on 2nd storage using:

```
mysql --login-path=kp test_db < dump.sql
```

But deletion of tables *T2,T3* on the 1st storage is not propagated this way to the 2nd storage.

How to propagate deletion of tables from the 1st storage to 2nd storage using *mysqldump* on the 1st and import of the dump on the 2nd?

Comment: Is Replication involved?

Comment: no, it's single server installation

Answer (score 1):

You need to drop and re-create the database. So you need to use some extra / different options when creating the dump file:

```
mysqldump --login-path=lp --add-drop-database --databases test_db > dump.sql
```

And import with:

```
mysql --login-path=kp < dump.sql
```